# Angular 7 Run ng serve -o -c env

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

Some time ago I was working with angular 6 and testing different environments using `ng serve -o -c env_i_wanted`.

I added de desired environments under configurations in the angular.json file.

In angular 7 I tried the same but got a something like this:

```
Project 'stage' could not be found in workspace.
Error: Project 'stage' could not be found in workspace.
    at Workspace.getProject (/Users/zjarr/Documents/Oktara/Websites/GoSweatHome/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace.js:93:19)
    at Architect.getBuilderConfiguration (/Users/zjarr/Documents/Oktara/Websites/GoSweatHome/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect.js:96:41)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (/Users/zjarr/Documents/Oktara/Websites/GoSweatHome/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:81:52)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:696:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

stage being the environment I want to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it now requires the name of the project: https://angular.io/cli/serve

For example: `ng s project_name -o --c stage`